# IBM Watson Chatbot - Read & Write to CSV/excel

Tags: ibm-cloud, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, ibm-watson

I'm currently in the process of creating a chatbot that is able to answer customer queries by looking at a CSV files and providing customers with the correct response.

I have seen many chatbot examples, however none seem to have the capability to read and write to a CSV (this is where all the relevant information is currently stored).

An example of reading from a CSV file:
A customer will ask the chatbot how much stock we have on a certain product. This information is currently held in csv files, where we want the chatbot to look at this file, find the correct product and return the stock level to the customer

An example of writing to a CSV file:
Customers will be able to use the chatbot to order products and once a customer order is placed, we would like this to be saved in this file.

Can anyone help here or know if this is possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That could be done with [dialog actions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions). Depending on your overall solution architecture server, client side or web actions can be used.

Basically, when Watson Assistant would need to look up data from the / a CSV, it would call the action with the "query" information. The result data is then used to form the answer.

Here is a [tutorial that uses actions for interfacing with a relational database (SQL)](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html). But you could change the code to open a CSV file, look something up and return it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Henrik!
If I'm honest, I'm not quite experienced with all of this...

Could you please provide an example code for a dialog action to read a CSV in my local directory (for test purposes) to check the stock levels of something? Just so i can see how it works.

Comment: There are tons of code samples available for each programming language on how to read a CSV file and process its input.

Comment: Yep I've seen code samples for many programming languages, however I cannot seem to find any code in the required JSON format the dialog actions require..

Comment: There are code samples for dialog actions (see the linked tutorial). Adapt it to the CSV code